# Python Multiprocessing - coding for a dual, quad and six core cpus

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a quick question on Python multiprocessing.

I am writing some code which will use multiprocessing to split tasks between cores/virtual cores but I have a number of machines and each has a different CPU...

I have an Intel Centrino2 dual core, an Intel i5 quad core and a dual Xeon hex core (with hyper threading) machine that will run this code.

This means that each machine will either have 2, 4 or 12/24 cores and I want to know if the same code will run on all machines or if I will need to tailor it for the specific number of cores on each machine...

I am thinking that the (upto) 10 python processes my code will create will run on a physical/virtual core if one is available but if the machine only has 2 or 4 cores, then the processes will run 'time-sliced' on the available cores similar to as they would if I were using threading - is this correct?

I will must likely 'suck it and see' but I am interested in any advice or information on this topic that you can suggest...

I am planning to run the code on 64 bit Centos Linux and Windows 10 OSes and use Anaconda Python 3.6 in case this is useful.

Thanks

Comment: `multiprocessing.cpu_count` and `os.cpu_count` _try_ (but may fail) to get the number of CPUs in your system, so you can use this information to create the most suitable number of processes to run.

Comment: Thanks ForceBru - I can see how this will be useful in the code to query the CPU and make changes on the fly based on the number of cores, if needed... I'm trying to understand more on what will happen if I try to spawn more processes than there are cores on the host machine...

Comment: there _are_ always more processes than cores your CPU has. No more than one process can use a single core at once, so what these processes do is... constantly interrupt each other. However, this happens so quickly it's almost impossible to notice. So, if you run 6 processes doing hard work on a quad-core CPU, the CPU will be constantly switching between them and the other processes. And if each of them will use 100% of each core, the switching will lower the efficiency of execution considerably.

Comment: In other words, once you launch, let's say, `N` processes more than the number of cores your CPU has, given that each process uses a considerable amount of a core's power, you'll get a slowdown. And the more processes you continue to launch, the slower your program will become.

Comment: lol - I wanted info on how the Python module 'multiprocessing' deals with allocating n processes to y cores where y is less n. I have up-voted your comments out of courtesy as they may be useful for those who don't know how a CPU works - hopefully someone else will be able to give an answer to my actual question on how the python multiprocessing module will behave on the 3 types of CPU... as I was looking for something along the lines of 'Python will just run the processes on the available cores and time-slice them as if they were threads...' which I kind of suspected anyway...

Comment: I think there has been some confusion on terminology - by processes I meant a python process allocated to its own core via the Python multiprocessing module...

Comment: there's nothing special about the module: it just launches ordinary processes, and each of them will try to occupy a CPU core. This is, however, different from Python threads because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) which forces the interpreter to execute only one `threading.Thread` at a time, so, no 'real' parallel processing (multithreading) is achieved this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Q/A on Stackoverflow which supports what I had originally thought - the code will run on any of the 3 cpus so will not need to be tailored on a per cpu basis...

[python multiprocessing and number of cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782824/python-multiprocessing-and-number-of-cores?rq=1)

Windows vs Linux performance:

As a side note to the above, there are some performance issues around spawning python multiprocessing processes on Window vs Linux, as in Windows, processes are 'heavy' and take more time/resources to create than on Linux platforms - this may mean that a python program using multiprocessing performs slightly better on Linux vs Windows.

Sharing data between processes via a multi-process queue (Overview):

Python multiprocessing differs from threading in as much as each process runs in its own address space so any data contained within a process isn't available to other processes by default - here is a good video which explains how to share data between processes using queuing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sp7EhjLkFY4